# Parse.com : issue sending iOS push notifications with the javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I want to send push notifications using the Javascript SDK with content-available = 1

According to Parse.com documentation I should do it this way :

```
Parse.Push.send({
  channels: [ "Mets" ],
  data: {
    alert: "The Mets scored! The game is now tied 1-1.",
    badge: "Increment",
    sound: "cheering.caf",
    title: "Mets Score!"
  }
}, {
  success: function() {
    // Push was successful
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // Handle error
  }
});
```

The problem is Javascript does not accept `content-available` as a key because of the "-".

I tried to put `"content-availabe"` between quotes. But then It is not recognized by iOS.

To make sure the quotes are not a solution, I tried it with the `sound` field.

```
sound : "ring.wav" // works very well

"sound" : "ring.wav" // no sound is played !!!
```

So how do I set `content-available` to `1` ?

Comment: are you sure  "content-available" : "1", is not working because it works on my app